# Kinect Joint Scale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect, oculus

I am trying to find a way to link the Kinect joints to the body parts of a character in Unity using Final IK.

Right now, all the joints are linked with the body parts correctly (I can move and the movement is duplicated to the character), but it seems like the scale between the joints (sent by the Kinect) is way smaller than the scale of the body parts. For example, when the Kinect detects my body, the character seems to collapse on itself. When I move, the movement is detected, but it is really small compared to the character's body.

Is there a way to sync those two scales?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way of doing this and it works quite well. I'll try to keep this as simple as possible.

The main problem I had was to get a value of scale from the Kinect Joints that would be applicable to the size of my caracter.

In order to solve this, I added a calibration method that performs the following actions :

1. Ask the user to maintain a T position.
2. Reads the length of the left arm of the user (kinect)
3. Reads the length of the left arm of the character in game.
4. Compare both length and find a relative scale (ex: if the left arm lengths returned by the kinect if 4 and the caracter has a left arm of 2, then the scale to have is 4/2 = 2)

I had a small issue at first but ended up solving it. The values of Vector3 returned by the Kinect in Unity are relative to the Kinect's origin (camera). There for, I had to use a bit of linear algebra to solve this. Since both Vector3 (left hand and left shoulder) are relative to the Kinect's origin, I had to substract them in order to find the left arm length.
[image: Linear Algebra Screenshot]

Thanks to linear algebra, we know that A + C = B, therefore, we can say that B - A = C. In our case, LeftHand - LeftShoulder = Left Arm. By applying this principle to the Vector3 received by the kinect, we now have the vector that represents the left arm. All we need to do is get the "magnitude" property and we now have its length.

That pretty much sums it up.